# OpenCobolIDE stopped working after macOS Mojave update

Tags: macos, compatibility, gnucobol

Before updating to macOS Mojave, OpenCobolIDE was working fine, but ever since I updated, every time I try to open the application, it just closes a second after I pressed the icon. This I probably compatibility issues with the now OS, but is there any methods to fix it without downgrading my OS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest to check the log first. https://opencobolide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=log#where-can-i-find-ocide-s-log-file says: You can find the OCIDE log file here: ~/Library/Caches/OpenCobolIDE/OpenCobolIDE.log

Comment: And I highly suggest to replace COBOL by [macos] tag...

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with OpenCobolIDE 4.7.4 on Mac after upgrade to Mojave - the program gets stalled with spinning wheel. Instead of using the download on https://launchpad.net/cobcide/+download, I have installed it with pip3:

In a terminal window I ran the command : `sudo pip3 install OpenCobolIDE --upgrade`

For more info see https://gist.github.com/ejlp12/4f59bd35cbfe4c5ffcf7955d5680a298

It installs OpenCobolIDE 4.7.6 and it runs smoothly after installation. The executable can be found in /usr/local/bin